# Access $routeparams from abstract state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Is it possible to access $routeParams in this case the id parameter within the abstract ProfileCtrl?

```
.state('profile', {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/profile",
            templateUrl: 'profile.html',
            controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
        })
        .state('profile.items', {
            url: "/:id/items",
            views: {
                'profile': {
                    templateUrl: 'ProfileItems.html',
                    controller: 'ProfileItemsCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProfileCtrl can only get parameters of it's url. Use the following:

```
.state('profile', {
    abstract: true,
    url: "/profile/:id",
    templateUrl: 'profile.html',
    controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
})
.state('profile.items', {
    url: "/items",
    views: {
        'profile': {
            templateUrl: 'ProfileItems.html',
            controller: 'ProfileItemsCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

This way ProfileCtrl is able to get the profile id. It can fetch the profile data and attach it to the $scope. This way any child of profile state will have access to the profile data (due to $scope inheritance).

Hope this helps!